# Issue with multiple mysql joins

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

I have 5 tables.

**This is my table sequence**

```
1. tbl_item_cate_values
2. tbl_cata_cate_multilang
3. tbl_catalog_category
4. tbl_data_type
5. tbl_cata_cate_type_mulitlang
```

**JOIN linking**

1. tbl_item_cate_values.item_id =  tbl_cata_cate_multilang.category_id
2. tbl_cata_cate_multilang.id = tbl_catalog_category.catalog_id
3. tbl_catalog_category.data_type_id = tbl_data_type.id
4. tbl_cata_cate_type_mulitlang.category_id = tbl_cata_cate_multilang.category_id

JOIN 3 tbl_data_type.data_type_name is 'dropdown' so JOIN tables tbl_cata_cate_type_mulitlang.category_id = tbl_cata_cate_multilang.category_id otherwise JOIN only first 3 tables how can I do this, thank you advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info on  why you do not want to join the 4th table if tbl_data_type.data_type_name is 'dropdown'??

Comment: Try by joining 4th table and in JOIN condition add `tbl_cata_cate_type_mulitlang.category_id = tbl_cata_cate_multilang.category_id AND tbl_data_type.data_type_name = 'dropdown' `

Comment: SameerK if no 'dropdown' value find  then skip 5th and 1th join.
Can  you please give me full query sameerK

Comment: You have a front-end. So before you make the call, block it out there. It is not as if you should always shove all the stuff to sql to figure out. PHP is a much more robust programming language to say the least. Use an `if` statement in PHP

Comment: You are right Drew, I done using php programming, but I have large Data and query is in loop so it's take a time so think mysql programming is better.